# I need something similar to a 3" to 5" curtain tension rod to fix my popping air ducts

Tags: mechanical-engineering, metals, solid-mechanics

The air ducts in my house have a couple of places where they make popping sounds as they expand while heating, one of the loudest ones is annoyingly in my bedroom.

I know by pressing around where I need to add compression against the wall in order to secure it in place to stop the popping. But I can't get a drill/screw in there since the hole is too small. My thought is if I can find something like a curtain tension rod I can put it inside the duct and push the walls apart which would give it no option to shift around in that area.

Problem is I absolutely can't find a tension rod short enough online. Is there a similar tool I can use that can range between 3" - 5" in length and acts like a tension rod?

Comment: The air duct *has* to move somehow when cooling/warming. By further constraining it, you force it to move somewhere else. consider adding a compensator, changing the routing or chaning the mounting so the air duct can expand and shrink without popping noises.

Comment: I've tested by putting constant pressure on it, stops the popping. It's a similar effect to having thicker duct material in the first place, requires more air pressure to create a pop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would find, or make, a tube with a thread that has an internal tube also threaded.

Then with rubber feet to stop slipping the rod can be unscrewed to tighten it into place as it will increase in length. I suggest a threaded device since the slip type extending rods such as used on tripods will be difficult to get tight.

Another thought is one of those spring loaded shower rods - both sides will need cutting to size. Or wedge wood dowel cut to fit across the gap - cheap and may work.